# alloc() error in swift

Tags: parsing, rss, swift2, alloc

So I've just updated my swift to 2.0 and obviously a couple of errors appeared in my code.
Thats what I have right now.

```
unc loadRssFeed(data: NSURL) {

    var myRssParser : ParserManager = ParserManager.alloc().initWithURL(data) as! ParserManager

    myRssFeed = myRssParser.feeds

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Fixit suggests to change 'var' to 'let' and use object initializer instead of alloc(). But the problem is I've never used it before (granted my Swift experience is like four weeks).

Should I follow fixit instruction?
And how do I fix the alloc() problem.

Thanks!

Updated wit parser code:

```
class ParserManager: NSObject, NSXMLParserDelegate {

var parser = NSXMLParser()
var feeds = NSMutableArray()
var elements = NSMutableDictionary()
var element = NSString()
var ftitle = NSMutableString()
var link = NSMutableString()
var fdescription = NSMutableString()
var fdate = NSMutableString()


func initWithURL(url :NSURL) -> AnyObject {
    startParse(url)
    return self
}
func startParse(url :NSURL) {
    feeds = []
    parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: url)!
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.shouldProcessNamespaces = false
    parser.shouldReportNamespacePrefixes = false
    parser.shouldResolveExternalEntities = false
    parser.parse()
}

func allFeeds() -> NSMutableArray {
    return feeds
}
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {

    self.element = elementName

    if self.element == "item" {

        self.ftitle = ""
        self.fdescription = ""

        self.fdate = ""

    }
}
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {

    if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("item") {
        if ftitle != "" {
            elements.setObject(ftitle, forKey: "title")
        }



        if fdescription != "" {
            elements.setObject(fdescription, forKey: "description")
        }

        if fdate != "" {
            elements.setObject(fdate, forKey: "pubDate")
        }

        feeds.addObject(elements)
    }

}
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String?) {

    if element.isEqualToString("title") {
        ftitle.appendString(string!)

    }else if element.isEqualToString("description") {
        fdescription.appendString(string!)
    }else if element.isEqualToString("pubDate") {
        fdate.appendString(string!)
    }
}


}
```

Comment: It should simply be `let parser = ParserManager(URL: data)`. Don't call `alloc` and `init` like this.

Comment: Now it says that there is extra argument 'URL' in call.
Will it help if I add my parser code to my original post?

Comment: That `initWithURL` In the `ParserManager` class should be `init` method with `URL` parameter.

Comment: Like that?

convenience init (url: NSURL)

Comment: Just do `init(URL: NSURL)` and then (a) use `URL`, not `url` within that method; (b) call `super.init()`; and (c) remove the `return self` call. See _The Swift Language_ guide for guidance on `init` methods.

Comment: Thanks, that worked out just fine!

Comment: BTW, if your URL is a web resource (as opposed to a local file URL), you really shouldn't be using `NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL)`. That performs a synchronous network request, but you should never block the main thread. Let us know if you'd like to see how to do that request a asynchronously.

Comment: That would be great! Should this conversation be moved to chat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed above, you should not call `alloc` and `init...` methods directly. Furthermore, the `ParserManager` class should not have a `initWithURL` method, but rather an `init` method with a `URL` parameter. The existing code is appearing to follow Objective-C patterns, but Swift has its own conventions.

But more broadly, I would advise against performing synchronous network requests, and when you're calling `NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL:)`, that's what's happening. It's better to request data asynchronously, and then refactor the code to follow asynchronous patterns (e.g. `completionHandler` closures). For example:

```
class ParserManager: NSObject, NSXMLParserDelegate {

    /// The NSMutableArray used internally by this class

    private var feeds = NSMutableArray()

    /// Initiate parsing asynchronously; note, I'm returning the `NSURLSessionTask` in case you want to cancel it at some later point

    func parse(URL: NSURL, completionHandler: (NSMutableArray?, NSError?)->()) -> NSURLSessionTask {
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(URL) { data, response, error in
            guard data != nil else {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    completionHandler(nil, error)
                }
                return
            }

            let parser = NSXMLParser(data: data!)
            parser.delegate = self

            if parser.parse() {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    completionHandler(self.feeds, nil)
                }
            } else {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    completionHandler(nil, parser.parserError)
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()

        return task
    }

    // NSXMLParserDelegate methods implemented here

}
```

Then, you can use the completion handler syntax to specify what you want to do when the network request and parsing is done:

```
let URL = NSURL(string: "...")
let myRssParser = ParserManager()
myRssParser.parse(URL) { feeds, error in
    guard feeds != nil else {
        print(error)
        return
    }

    // use `feeds` here, e.g.

    self.feeds = feeds            // update your local property
    self.tableView.reloadData()   // and reload the table
}

// but don't use `feeds` here, since it won't be done by the time we get here
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the effort! I will try this out. Honestly didn't expect something like that. Thank you again!

Comment: FYI, by moving the URL out of the `init` method and into a parameter of the `parse` method, you can enjoy considerable further simplification (eliminate `init` method entirely, remove a bunch of properties, etc.). See revised answer.

Answer (score 2):

The fix should look like this:

```
let myRssParser = ParserManager(URL: data) as! ParserManager
```

Or maybe like this, depends upon how ParserManager has been written:

```
let myRssParser = ParserManager(url: data) as! ParserManager
```

There's even a possibility that you don't have to use the argument name:

```
let myRssParser = ParserManager(data) as! ParserManager
```

Comment: It's not me for sure.
Now it says that there is extra argument 'URL' in call. Will it help if I add my parser code to my original post?

Comment: Seems like it, Thanks!

But now there is a problem with converting NSURL to  expected() so it seems like I need to look into my ParserManager code.

Comment: The second solution gives me 'extra 'url' on call' :(

I guess I will try to try something else.

But anyway, thanks for your help!